# Lights-out puzzle on a large grid

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to solve [this](https://dunjudge.me/analysis/problems/1188/) algorithmic problem. For convenience, I have replicated it below:

> We are given a grid G of size N x M (1 <= N,M <= 1000) containing only 1s and 0s. If we choose one of the cells, this will toggle the value in adjacent cells (and that cell itself). Two cells that differ by exactly 1 row or 1 column are considered adjacent (i.e. diagonal cells are not adjacent). Our goal is to find a grid G' containing 1s at cell positions that we need to choose in order to turn all cells in G to 0 (those cells that we don't have to choose are marked with 0). Given any G (in this problem), G' is guaranteed to exist.
>
> Note: There is no wraparound in the grid.

For example, if G is given as the following:

```
000
100
000
```

If we choose the center cell, G will become:

```
010
011
010
```

For this example, G' is:

```
001
011
001
```

It looks very similar to the [lights-out puzzle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LightsOutPuzzle.html). I am only able to solve this for small instances (N,M <= 20) using brute force. A search on google also yields a solution (for the lights-out puzzle) that uses Gaussian elimination. But this only works on small grids (N,M <= 100) since this method has a cubic time complexity.

Could someone please advise me on how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Gaussian elimination doesn't have cubic time complexity.  It takes O(N^3) time for NxN matrices, but in terms of the input size, that's just O(N^1.5)

To solve the lights out puzzle on an NxM grid with Gaussian elimination takes O(N^2*M) time and O(N*M) space, where N can be whichever dimension is smaller.

On an average PC or MAC you should be able to do 1000x1000 in a small number of seconds in C++ or Java if you make sure the inner loops are fast.

Comment: Hmm. Since a Gaussian elimination solution takes O(N^2*M) time where N,M <= 1000. We will do 1000^3 operations at most which is going to be really slow.

Comment: 1000^3 is not that slow these days.  Most of these can be bit-parallel too